# Changing the text of a button by clicking another button?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Whenever I click the **Detect** button, I want the **0/1000** button to update. When I click it once, it turns into **1/1000**. If I click it twice, it turns into **2/1000** and so on. How would I do this? I have this so far and it didn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

score = 0
max_score = 1000

root = Tk()
root.title('Gamerscore')
root.geometry('600x400')
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight='1')
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight='1')

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton",
                font="Serif 15",
                padding=10)


def button_detect_press():
    score += 1
    button_score = ttk.Button(main_frame, text=str(score) + '/' + str(max_score)).grid(row=1, column=0)


main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

button_score = ttk.Button(main_frame, text=str(score) + '/' + str(max_score)).grid(row=1, column=0)
button_detect = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Detect', command=button_detect_press).grid(row=4, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are trying to modifying a global variable in a local function. Therefore you need to declare `global score` in your `button_detect_press` function before `score+=1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new button on each click. Instead, you want to call the `configure` method on the existing button.

That requires two changes. First, you need to separate the creation of the button from its layout. This is necessary because `ttk.Button(...).grid(...)` returns the value of `grid(...)`, and that always returns None. Plus, in my experience, separating them makes the layout easier to visualize when reading the code, and it makes it easier to write the code.

So, create and layout the buttons like this:

```
button_score = ttk.Button(main_frame, text=str(score) + '/' + str(max_score))
button_detect = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Detect', command=button_detect_press)

button_score.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_detect.grid(row=4, column=0)
```

Next, modify `button_detect_press` to call the `configure` method on `button_score`. Also, because you're modifying `score` it needs to be declared as global:

```
def button_detect_press():
    global score
    score += 1
    text = str(score) + '/' + str(max_score))
    button_score.configure(text=text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I do all of this, I get this error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score' referenced before assignment

Comment: I fixed it. Just had to make an iteration of score = 0 and place it inside the function. But now, when I click detect, it brings it to 1 and then the clicks no longer do anything. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Need to declare `global score` inside `button_detect_press()` instead of `make an iteration of score = 0`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!